# CSV file is logged as html file

Tags: javascript, html

When I try to read in a csv file it gets logged to the console as the html file of the home page, which the code isn't being run on.

I've tried changing the url but nothing works

```
window.onload = function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "footage.csv",
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(data) {
          processData(data);
       }
    });
}

function processData(data){
     console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: change the datatype to   dataType: "text/csv",

Comment: Now nothing is logged to console

Comment: Your server sends html, you've to check the server-side code instead. Notice, that setting `dataType` doesn't force your server to return the data in a specific format, `dataType` hints to jQuery how to handle the data.